# How to run "cat file1 | tr -d '\r' > file2" in Python?

Tags: python

What is the best way to call following unix command in Python? `cat file1.txt | tr -d '\r' > file2.txt`
I tried following cases: 
1.

```
cmd = "cat file1 | tr -d \'\r\'> file2"
args = shlex.split(cmd)
p = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=True)
```

I got `cat: stdin: Input/output error`

2.

```
f = open(file2, "w")
p = subprocess.call(args, stdout=f)
```

I got:

`cat: |: No such file or directory`
`cat: tr: No such file or directory`
`cat: -d: No such file or directory`
`cat: \r: No such file or directory`

3.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
(out,err) = p.communicate()
print(out)
```

It works, but I do not know why when I use `file.write(out)` instead of `print(out)`, I get the same error as case 2.

Comment: I might get told to answer the question as asked, but: there's no reason to use cat and tr from Python to remove carriage returns. Open the file, read the data, and write it out transformed.

Comment: @Ned Batchelder, the file may be pretty big, so I do not want to open and edit it in python.

Comment: @Shabnam you don't have to have all the data in memory. Your Python program can do just what tr does.

Answer (score 1):

Just do it in Python:

```
with open("file1.txt", "rb") as fin:
    with open("file2.txt", "wb") as fout:
        while True:
            data = fin.read(100000)
            if not data:
                break
            data = data.replace(b"\r", b"")
            fout.write(data)
```

Comment: Would doing `fin.read(fin._CHUNK_SIZE)` be beneficial here? Ever since I noticed files have a `_CHUNK_SIZE` attribute, I've had a hunch that this value might be optimized for optimal disk read operations but never really could mentally justify it since it means more iterations in python-land.

Comment: I've never header of _CHUNK_SIZE, and don't know how it would affect things. I expect this would be limited by the I/O speed anyway, but you'd have to time it if it really matters.